# How can I reference other servers in the same inventory by group name?

Tags: ansible

I have a static inventory that contains groups and servers inside these groups. Group names can change and so the server names. I'm passing group names as a variable during runtime to the playbook. I'm trying to check a bunch of ports between different servers in the inventory.

So if this is the inventory

```
group1
  server1

group2
  server2
  server3
```

And I have group1 and group2 as variables.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
hosts: group1_var
tasks:
 - name: test connection
   ansible.windows.win_wait_for:
   host: **{{groups[group2_var]}}**   ##How do I implement this correctly????
   port: 443
   delay: 3
```

Also a second part to this question, but I cannot for some reason return the value of the magic variable if groupX is a variable. When it's a simple string it returns the server names ok.

```
debug : msg="{{groups['{{groupX}}']))"
```

Comment: To the one who voted as off-topic because not a programming question: this is a typical loop/control structure problem hence definitely a programming question. And even thought it is a basic question, it is absolutely on-topic Testing connection between machines is only the task ran inside the loop(s) and is not the actual problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question.

- You have a source group and target group of server(s)
- You want to pass those dynamically to your playbook at run time
- You want to run a task on each server in the source group for each server in the target group.

You actually need two loops. The first one is the natural play loop (i.e. `hosts` parameter in your play). The second `loop:` will be on your task. I used a debug task for the example. You just have to report the loop on your own task.

Given the inventory `inventories/default/main.yml`

```yaml
---
group1:
  hosts:
    server1:

group2:
  hosts:
    server2:
    server3:
```

And the following `playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ source_group }}"
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: test connection
      debug:
        msg: "testing connection from {{ inventory_hostname }} to {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups[target_group] }}"
```

You can check connections from `group1` to `group2`

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ playbook.yml \
  -e source_group=group1 -e target_group=group2

PLAY [group1] ********************************************************

TASK [test connection] ***********************************************
ok: [server1] => (item=server2) => {
    "msg": "testing connection from server1 to server2"
}
ok: [server1] => (item=server3) => {
    "msg": "testing connection from server1 to server3"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************
server1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Or from `group2` to `group1`

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ playbook.yml \
  -e source_group=group2 -e target_group=group1

PLAY [group2] ********************************************************

TASK [test connection] ***********************************************
ok: [server2] => (item=server1) => {
    "msg": "testing connection from server2 to server1"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=server1) => {
    "msg": "testing connection from server3 to server1"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************
server2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Or even from `group2` to `group2` itself

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ playbook.yml \
  -e source_group=group2 -e target_group=group2

PLAY [group2] ********************************************************

TASK [test connection] ***********************************************
ok: [server2] => (item=server2) => {
    "msg": "testing connection from server2 to server2"
}
ok: [server2] => (item=server3) => {
    "msg": "testing connection from server2 to server3"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=server2) => {
    "msg": "testing connection from server3 to server2"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=server3) => {
    "msg": "testing connection from server3 to server3"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************
server2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description

> *... check ... ports between different servers in the inventory*

I understand that you like to do connection test from servers in `group1` to servers in `group2`

```
group1 --------> group2
```

```
            ---> server2
server1 ---|
            ---> server3
```

and whereby servers in `group1` (`server1`) are not the Ansible Control Node.

To do so you could use an approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show connection test
    delegate_to: group1
    debug:
      msg: "Connect from 'group1' node to {{ inventory_hostname }}"
    when: "'group2' in group_names"
```

resulting into

```yaml
TASK [Show connection test] ****************
ok: [server2 -> server1] =>
  msg: Connect from 'group1' node to server2
ok: [server3 -> server1] =>
  msg: Connect from 'group1' node to server3
```

**Documentation**

- [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)
- [Sepcial variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)
- [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)

---

Regarding

> *I cannot for some reason return the value of the magic variable if groupX is a variable.*

you may have a look into the following example

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ target_group }}" # aka group_var
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    group_x: "group1"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ groups[group_x] }}"
```

and

**FAQ**

- [When should I use `{{ }}`? Also, how to interpolate variables or dynamic variable names?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)